# Connect to postgres container from another running container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

I am struggling to connect to a running container with a postgres database from another container. I can connect when running locally, but I suspect that there is some networking issue that I'm overlooking when trying to connect from another container. The specific error I am currently seeing is `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "my_network" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'                                                                                       
services:                                                                                          
  data_collection:                                                                                 
    build: ./docker/data_collection                                                                
    ports:                                                                                         
      - "8888:8888"                                                                                
      - "6006:6006"                                                                                
      - "8000:8000"                                                                                                           
    networks:                                                                                      
      - my_network                                                                                 
    depends_on:                                                                                    
      - db                                                                                         
  db:                                                                                              
    image: 'postgres:13.2-alpine'                                                                  
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - POSTGRES_DB=spotify
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data # persist data even if container shuts down               
    networks:
      - my_network                                                                                 
                                                                                                   volumes:                                                                                           
  db-data: # names volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose                                                                                                                                 
networks:                                                                                          
  my_network:                                                                                      
~
```

I then enter a shell in my `data_colleciton` container and try to connect by reading those params into a variables `params`, which gets passed in like this:

```
import psycopg2

params = dict(host='my_network', database='spotify', user='postgres', password='mypassword', port='5432')
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
```

However, running this locally and replacing the host above with localhost does work as expected

Comment: It's safe to remove all of the `networks:` blocks and all mentions of `my_network`; Compose [automatically creates a network named `default`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  Doing this will simplify the Compose setup and might remove some ambiguity for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `host='my_network'` to `host='db'`. You are not connecting to the network, you are connecting to a specific host in that network.

Comment: Ah, such an obvious thing! Thank you!